# How to intercept all click events in an activity?

Tags: android

I have some views that I have performed `view.setOnClickListener(listener)` on.

I currently want to intercept all click events, check where they occurred and do some pre-processing before handing the events off to be processed normally. Is this possible?

```
private View.OnTouchListener exampleListener = new View.OnTouchListener()
{
    // some kind of middleware for click events basically
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        int action = event.getAction();

        if (isAClick(action) && inSomeRectOfScreen(action))
        {
            doSomething();

            return false; // pass handling to normal view hierarchy
        }
        else
        {
            return false; // pass handling to normal view hierarchy
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: What is the issue with your implementation ?

Comment: You don't need a custom `View`. Override `Activity`'s `dispatchTouchEvent()`. Just return the `super` call return, and you won't be interfering with anything.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You make a custom view for the root view and implement `onInterceptTouchEvent`.  But its really not a great idea to be doing this, its not how an android app is expected to be implemented. Its going to be fragile.  A better idea is to post what you're attempting to do with this and see if there's a way around needing to.

Comment: Yeah I figured I was going to have to either override `dispatchTouchEvent` or `onInterceptTouchEvent`

Comment: You already mentioned it that its not a good idea to do this but you still suggest for him to do it. There will be problem with him trying to implement it this way in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just create a single method like

```
Public void onClick(View v) {
      Switch(v.id) {
              // your code
      }
}
```

And basically use that method on all your view which needs the click listener...

You can even add that to the xml layout like soo

```
<View
    ....
    android:onClick="onClick"
    .../>
```

Comment: Because it doesn't really help what he's trying to do.  He'd have to add this on every view, which for anything non-trivial would be a nightmare to maintain.  There's better solutions.  Also, this deals with clicks, not touches.  Two separate things.  A click is a certain pattern of touches. (down, little movement, then up in a relatively fast cadence)

Comment: There are give and takes for all solutions. Adding that onTouchEvent means making him handle all touch events including swipe, click, drag, etc. Doing that correctly is way harder to maintain rather than just adding the click listeners to the view who could receive the clicks. Plus he is explicitly asking for click events.

Comment: Also I just because you think theres a better solution means a different answer is already invalid.

Answer (score -2):

try to call a recrecive function from parent to all children like this

```
public void setupUI(View view) {
        view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {   
        doSomething();
             return false;
            }

        });
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
                View innerView = ((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i);
                setupUI(innerView);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In addition to being inefficient, this will break any view that expects to interact with touches.  It also will break accessibility tools, as you aren't generating click events which many of them work on.